# How to make Brother DCP540CN scanner function in 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, 16.04, scanner

I've been using Ubuntu for a few years and I'm very happy with it. Two days ago I wiped my hard drive and installed 16.04 LTS (64 bit). I was using 14.04 LTS prior to this. since doing this I've been attempting to get my networked Brother DCP540CN to work properly. The printer portion works fine using whichever install method that Brother supplies, but I cannot get the scanner to function or even be recognized by xsane. I've been working with this multi function printer and Ubuntu for a few years without problems, so I know that it works fine (in 14.04 LTS 64 bit). I tried removing all of the drivers and installing the 32 bit drivers, but another problem arose with dependencies, so I had to return to the 64 bit drivers. Does anyone have any insight into how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ppa from sane stuff ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git for the latest sane-backends, type in terminal "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git", and accept the key by pressing enter, as you should know that you have to have installed sane package to use your scanner in Linux or you can install that after adding the ppa because all scanners in Linux are supported through sane project. So I do not know if you know that if your scanner was working in the previous release then you were already using that scanner with help of sane-backends. You just have to do it again this way. And there is another way, compiling the package from the latest sane-backend source but trust me, the former one is easier.

Answer (score 0):

See https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Scanner/Brother/ (German site). Worked for me with a Brother DCP-585CW.
They write almost at the bottom of the article (translated):

> **Scanning via network since Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit)**
>
> Since Ubuntu 16.04 the scanner does no longer work in ScanLite and probably all other applications using `sane` either. The network scanner is not found after launching the application although installing the Brother scanner .deb package seemingly worked. Same applies for the Brother driver install tool.
>
> After installing the scanner driver, this has helped:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/libbrscandec3.so* /usr/lib 
> sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/sane
> sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother3.so* /usr/lib/sane
> ```
>
> and eventually as well this:
>
> ```
> sudo adduser USERNAME. scanner
> ```
>
> After that, reboot your computer and network scanning with ScanLite should work again.
>
> This is because Brother installs its files in `/usr/lib64`, but since Ubuntu 16.04, they are expected to be in `/usr/lib` instead.

Comment: Would you mind translating that section?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I translated it.

Comment: I had to copy the files to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane instead maybe because i upgraded  from ubuntu 14.04 that was upgraded from 12.04