# Brother DCP-7055W scanner not found

Tags: scanner

My Brother DCP-7055W combination printer/scanner worked properly before but now it cannot be found. I've done and redone the installation with Brother's install tool [linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=nl&lang=nl&prod=dcp7055_all&os=128&flang=English) and also fully done the suggestions from [a similar question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764322/how-to-make-brother-dcp540cn-scanner-function-in-16-04-lts). Moreover, in addition to the last command from the official installation, namely:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name="DCP-7055W" model=DCP-7055W ip=192.168.178.17
```

I've also issued the command

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=SCANNER model=DCP-7055W ip=192.168.178.17
```

Thus, the last three lines of the output of `brsaneconfig4 -q` are:

```
Devices on network
  0 SCANNER             "DCP-7055W"         I:192.168.178.17
  1 DCP-7055W           "DCP-7055W"         I:192.168.178.17
```

I've no problems with printing, but scanning doesn't work: `simple-scan`, `gscan2pdf`, and `xsane` all get stuck by not finding the scanner, even when I provide either of these device parameters: `brother4:net1;dev0` or `brother4:net1;dev1` (which were shown by `xscanimage` to select from).

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 on AMD A6-7470K Radeon R5, 6 Compute Cores 2C+4G × 2.
The output of `dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother` is:

```
ii  brscan-skey                                 0.2.4-1                                      amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                     0.4.5-1                                      amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  dcp7055wcupswrapper:i386                    3.0.1-1                                      i386         Brother DCP-7055W CUPS wrapper driver
ii  dcp7055wlpr:i386                            3.0.1-1                                      i386         Brother DCP-7055W LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                      3-5~ubuntu1                                  amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                       1.4-1                                        amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

(Note the two lines with "i368" in the third column; maybe they are obsolete and a remaining of previous installations, maybe the are right even for my installation since printing is not problematic.)

As far as I could see from the terminal screen, the following commands were executed by the official installation mentioned above:

```
dpkg -x dcp7055wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb /
dpkg -x dcp7055wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb /
dpkg -b ./brother_driver_packdir dcp7055wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
dpkg -b ./brother_driver_packdir dcp7055wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
dpkg -i --force-all dcp7055wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
dpkg -i --force-all dcp7055wcupswrapper-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
lpadmin -p DCP7055W -E -v dnssd://Brother%20DCP-7055W._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/ -P /usr/share/ppd/brother/brother-DCP-7055W-cups-en.ppd
aa-complain cupsd
lpadmin -p DCP7055W -v dnssd://Brother%20DCP-7055W._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/ -E
lpr -P DCP7055W /usr/share/cups/data/testprint
dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.5-1.amd64.deb
mdpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
brsaneconfig4 -a name=DCP-7055W model=DCP-7055W ip=192.168.178.17
```

Please help.

Comment: The `dpkg -x` commands may damage your system. Do not use it! Use `sudo apt-get install ./*.deb` or GDebi. I do not know what to do be Brother devices, I do not have any.

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for editing my question! (Sorry, I don't know how to send you this message other than by this comment.)

Comment: @N0rbert: I'll give your advice a try; how, exactly, should I replace the lines `dpkg -x FILE.deb  / `? (I cannot figure it out from `man dpgk` and `dpkg --help` and so on. Moreover, I'm not sure about the actually executed commands since the script for the official installation is over three thousand lines long.)

Comment: I now think that the problem is related to the IP address (ip=192.168.178.17). This used to work properly. How can I test whether this is a/the right one?

Answer (score 1):

The IP-address of the scanner was wrong, in the line:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name="DCP-7055W" model=DCP-7055W ip=192.168.178.17
```

I discovered this fact (and the right IP address) via the settings of the same scanner in a Windows 10 system in which the scanner was correctly functioning.